# How do I test a script using RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm writing a script that will be run using `rails runner` on production to make some one-time changes to our database. I want to be sure that the script works as expected before we run it, so I'm writing RSpec tests to verify its behavior while I write it.

How can I invoke the script in my test examples? The script isn't a class or a module, so there aren't individual functions for me to test. Instead, the entire script will be loaded once, run from top to bottom, and then exited. I'm not sure how to invoke that from within an RSpec test.

I'm looking for something like:

```rb
describe "my script" do
  it "should create the correct record" do
    before_count = Orders.count

    rails runner my_script.rb # What goes here?

    expect(Orders.count).to eq(before_count + 1)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I can use [`Kernel#load`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-load) to execute the script:

```rb
describe "my script" do
  it "should create the correct record" do
    before_count = Orders.count

    load(Rails.root.join("path", "to", "my-script.rb")

    expect(Orders.count).to eq(before_count + 1)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would move the logic from the script into its own class.  Then you can invoke the class in your script and in your tests or even when you're in the rails console.  I've been using this pattern for a while and its pretty useful.

Comment: I've considered doing this. The problem I have with it is, I want to be able to just hand the script to our sys ops team and let them run the script with `rails runner my-script.rb`. It seems to me that putting all the logic in a class would make it harder to hand the script to my coworkers without some convoluted instructions for running it.

Comment: If you are using `rails runner` you can do: `rails runner "SomeClass.run"`

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [system](https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/system):

```rb
system('rails runner my_script.rb')
```

---

edit #1

If you are willing to butcher the script, you can move the active components of your script into separate module and `require` that:

```rb
# my_script.rb
require './lib/my_script.rb'
MyScript.call()
```

```rb
# lib/my_script.rb
module MyScript
  def self.call
    # your code
  end
end
```

Then, in test:

```rb
require './lib/my_script.rb'

describe "my script" do
  it "should create the correct record" do
    before_count = Orders.count

    MyScript.call() # here

    expect(Orders.count).to eq(before_count + 1)
  end
end
```

Comment: Hmmm... I can do this, but is there a way to execute the script without spawning another process?

Comment: It's possible to do by putting your script code into module and requiring it. I edited the post to describe how

Answer (score 0):

We can help you with this, but this:

> I'm writing a script that will be run using rails runner on production to make some one-time changes to our database.

Is what migrations are for. One time changes like this to the db should be done in a migration. This circumvents the need for rspec, as any changes like this should be *reversible*, as migrations should be.

Comment: I don't think a migration is appropriate for this. I'm making one-time changes to the records in the database, not to the database schema. And the nature of the changes makes them both irreversible and something we wouldn't want to do again if we stand up a new database.

Comment: That is something my team does with migrations all the time. Migrations are key here because they create a log of what's happened. There's no logs for random scripts that get run.